# Is there any way to pass a whole model via html.actionlink in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I pass a whole model via `html.actionlink` or using any other method except form submission? Is there any way or tips for it?

Comment: did you try using `ViewData` ?

Comment: if there such a need, you are probably doing something wrong. Describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Though it's not advisable in complex cases, you can still do that!

```
public class QueryViewModel
{
  public string Search { get; set; }
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public int Page { get; set; }
}

// just for testing
@{
   var queryViewModel = new QueryViewModel
   {
      Search = "routing",
      Category = "mvc",
      Page = 23
   };
}

@Html.ActionLink("Looking for something", "SearchAction", "SearchController"
                  queryViewModel, null);
```

This will generate an action link with `href` like this,

*/SearchController/SearchAction?Search=routing&Category=mvc&Page=23*

Here will be your action,

```
public ViewResult SearchAction(QueryViewModel query)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: tx bro it was a gud tips for me and i had done a bit progress regard to ur post

Comment: Why is this not advisable?

Comment: If there are more properties in the class then the URL could become too big and also there are chances some sensitive information could be leaked.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot pass entire complex objects with links or forms. You have a couple of possible approaches that you could take:

- Include each individual property of the object as query string parameters (or input fields if you are using a form) so that the default model binder is able to reconstruct the object back in the controller action
- Pass only an id as query string parameter (or input field if you are using a form) and have the controller action use this id to retrieve the actual object from some data store
- Use session

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to detect a click on the link, serialize the form (or whatever data you want to pass) and append it to your request parameters. This should achieve what you're looking to achieve...

Comment: i don't know much about serializaition in javascript and u provide me an example if possible