# Asp.Net mvc pass model into ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So why isn't this working out for me?
I have a actionlink which should take a model instance back into the controller.

**Questions view**

```
@foreach (var question in Model.Select(item => item as Question))
{
  ..
  @Html.ActionLink(@question.Title, "SingleQuestion", "Posts", question, null)
  ..
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SingleQuestion(Question question)
{
   return View();
}
```

This won't work
**Error**
[image]

But when use this solution:
[Is there any way to pass a whole model via html.actionlink in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598190/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-whole-model-via-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

It does, Is this because a model instance can be to complex?

Thanks

Comment: Well, according to the error message your model doesn't have a parameterless constructor.  So the model binder can't create an instance of it.  You're either going to need to create a parameterless constructor or a custom model binder

Comment: It seems that your model has a constructor with parameters. In this case, you need another one **without** parameters like **public Question() {}** for EF. In the answear of the linked question, you pass the model as parameter - Not a very secure and clean way, you'd be better to pass a key like **QuestionId** as parameter. Then you can fetch the question related to the given id in the target ActionResult.

Comment: @David yes, i also tried adding a parameterless constructor but the model itselve is a child class.

Comment: @Lion Thanks for response, I'am going to try this out!

Comment: @JimVercoelen: Being a child class doesn't preclude having a parameterless constructor.  The model binder isn't really interested in the inheritance hierarchy of the class, just in creating an instance of it.

Comment: @David ow oke, yeah I am just started on asp so it's all a bit strange! But thanks for responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` helper method generates an anchor tag and clicking on which usually do a `GET` request to the target url.

You should not be trying to pass a complex object to a GET action method. You should be passing a unique id using which the GET action can rebuild/re-query your complex object and use that in your view.

```
@foreach (var question in Model.Select(item => item as Question))
{
  <p>
  @Html.ActionLink(@question.Title, "SingleQuestion", "Posts",
                                               new {questionId=question,Id}, null)
  </p>
}
```

And in your GET Action method

```
public ActionResult SingleQuestion(int questionId)
{
   Question q = GetQuestionFromSomeWhere(questionId);
   if(q!=null)
   {
     return View(q);
   }
   return View("NotFound");
}
```

Comment: Ow thanks, this is the same as Lion suggested? I am going to try this out, vote in a couple of minutes! Thanks for now

Comment: @JimVercoelen Yes. Read the answer for understanding the PRG pattern http://stackoverflow.com/a/11209320/40521

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here, with an id it is working!

Answer (score 0):

For your `Question` class, add at least 1 empty constructor with no parameters:

```
public class Question {
     public Question () {} //add this
     public Question (string param1) { //your constructor }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i fixed it with an other answer but I do appreciate for you help!